# Git rebase or merge

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-merge, git-rebase

I understand that re-base is good for situations when you want to add a fix to a base branch and put it in all other branches. but it seems much more complicated than a merge(much more conflicts).
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is a good practice to use `git rebase` when you are working on non-published things - local things that you have not pushed (or you have pushed to a place that other people are not pulling from). Rebase rewrites history, so people pulling will have issues if you rebase, while merge does not rewrite history, thus does not cause issues for other people.

While merge will try to merge your changes using a merge strategy, rebase will just fetch the HEAD of what you are rebasing against and then try to apply your changes. Since it loses the time of when your change was made, it can not solve conflicts as effectively as a merge.

Usually rebase is not much more complicated, unless you are in a relatively small codebase where a lot of developers are working at the same time and stepping on each others toes OR you leave your code for a long time.

I think this is a good resource to read about rebase: http://www.jarrodspillers.com/git/2009/08/19/git-merge-vs-git-rebase-avoiding-rebase-hell.html

Jarrod defines the "rebase rule" very well: Don’t rebase branches you have shared with another developer.

Comment: I asked about this elsewhere recently, but didn't really receive a satisfactory reply. Why is rebasing shared history such a problem? I have a feeling that it's because people aren't very good at rebasing, and it scares them, but I'd like to hear other reasons.

Comment: Rebase shared history is considered bad, because it beats the purpose of version control - rebasing is rewriting history. Also, it leads to major issues for other developers as they get into situation where you published something and the next day you change it, but they have what you previously published. Of course, if you would not use tracking branches and always fetch, you can use completely rebase based workflow, but I would not advice to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

From a correctness point of view, the only valid answer is to use `merge`: If you rebase a commit onto some other, you are creating a new commit with a state that never existed during development. A state that was likely not tested, which may not even compile, or be nonsensical in some other way.

An example: You branch of and develop some code that calls function `foo()`. The next day, another developer tells you, that `foo()` has some issues, due to which he's currently in the process of removing it. So you remove your calls of `foo()` with another commit, and proceed to finish your feature. If you now rebase your work onto the master which had `foo()` removed by your peer, none of your early commits will compile, even though the `rebase` operation might not encounter any conflicts.

This example just illustrates the fact that any rebased history is telling a lie: It does not truthfully tell you the history of the development, but deceives you with the illusion that development was a linear process. And these lies have consequences. `git` was designed for merging, and it's best to use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Rebase scares people before they know them. Here is actually a nice summary between rebase and merge:
Note that the snapshot pointed to by the final commit you end up with, whether it’s the last of the rebased commits ***for a rebase*** or the final merge commit ***after a merge***, ***is the same snapshot*** – ***it’s only the history that is different.*** Rebasing replays changes from one line of work onto another in the order they were introduced, whereas merging takes the endpoints and merges them together.