# git rebasing commit history not being pulled into branches

Tags: git, version-control

So, we have master, and branch X which is up to date with master, plus some more commits.

I've rebased master, changing history - squashing a few commits, rewording others.

I then try to rebase branch X with master - it seems that the rewords don't come across into branch X - they're still the old commit messages - how can I update branch Xs commit history to match master?

(Btw, it seems the squash and fixup rebases came across fine, it just seems to be the rewords).

Comment: Could you explain in detail the sequence of commands you used. Everything from how you rebased master, to everything you did to branch X. I recently had to rebase master, and believe me it can be painful.

Answer (score 1):

If you rebased your master, branch-X is no longer up to date with master. I think the easiest way to figure this out is to use git cherry-pick.

1. Make a new branch from master, `git checkout -b branch-Y master`
2. `git cherry-pick <sha>` for each commit that you need from branch-X
3. You can delete branch-X and rename branch-Y to branch-X `git branch -f branch-X branch-Y; git checkout branch-X; git branch -D branch-Y`

I also would suggest reading more about rebase before using it extensively: [Git rebase or merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610138/git-rebase-or-merge/13610439#13610439)

Comment: I need all of the commits from branch X. My problem is that when I rebase branch X with master, the reworded commits in Master don't take effect in branch X.

Reading the documentation, the --merge option should take note of the renamed commits, but it does not seem to work.